# Why this foldLeft scala code does not work?

Tags: scala

The following codesnippet is upposed to get me a hash map of `Map[String, (String, Int)]`.

```
def genList(xx: String) = {
    Seq("one", "two", "three", "four")
}

val oriwords = Set("hello", "how", "are", "you")
val newMap = (Map[String, (String, Int)]() /: oriwords) (
    (cmap, currentWord) => {
        val xv = 2

        genList(currentWord).map(ps => {
            val src = cmap get ps

            if(src == None) {
                cmap + (ps -> (w, xv))
            }
            else {
                if(src.get._2 < xv) {
                    cmap + (ps -> (w, xv))
                }
                else cmap
            }

        })
    }
)
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
error: too many arguments for method ->: (y: B)(String, B)
                       cmap + (ps -> (w, xv))
                                  ^
```

**Update:** With the suggested changes that are mentioned in the answers, the above error is removed.

```
val newMap = (Map[String, (String, Int)]() /: oriwords) (
    (cmap, currentWord) => {
        val xv = 2

        genList(currentWord).map(ps => {
            val src = cmap get ps

            if(src == None) {
                cmap + (ps -> ((currentWord, xv)))
            }
            else {
                if(src.get._2 < xv) {
                    cmap + (ps -> ((currentWord, xv)))
                }
                else cmap
            }

        })
    }
)
```

But now getting a new error on the above code as follows:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,(String, Int)]]
 required: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,(String, Int)]
               genList(currentWord).map(ps => {
                                       ^
```

Comment: Compiler sometimes gets confused with the implicit class that defines the `->` method. You're usually better off changing `a -> b` to `(a, b)`. You have more errors in this code, but this should take care of the weird "too many arguments" message that you're seeing.

Comment: Please do not edit your question in such a way that existing answers are invalidated. If you have a question, post a question.

Comment: you are giving Map[String,[(String, Int)] as the initial value but you are iterating over list and creating map inside it so it's returning you List[Map[String,(String,Int)]].

Comment: Every iteration of the fold, `/:`, needs to return a `Map[_,_]` but `genList()` is returning a `Seq[_]`, which you are mapping over to create a `Seq[Map[_,_]]`, which is not what what the fold requires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ps -> (w, xv)
```

is interpreted as

```
ps.->(w, xv)
```

i.e. as passing two arguments instead of what you intend, which is passing a 2-tuple as single argument:

```
ps.->((w, xv))
```

or in operator syntax:

```
ps -> ((w, xv))
```

Comment: Now I am getting another error after your changes. Please help. I have updated the description with the new error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an extra parenthesis as the single parenthesis is interpreted as method application:

```
cmap + (ps -> ((w, xv)))
```

which means:

```
cmap + (ps.->((w, xv)))
```

Or you can use the `->` twice:

```
cmap + (ps -> (w -> xv))
```